# GCP Cloud Shell Editor - Drag and Drop goes to blank screen

Tags: google-cloud-shell-editor

When using cloud shell editor with the latest version of Chrome, when I attempt to drag a file into a folder, the entire Cloud Shell Editor screen goes white (i.e. blank).  I have to refresh my page to bring the view back.  Drag and drop used to work on this machine, so I am not sure what happened to put it into this state.  I attempted to resolve the issue by clearing my cookies and cache, but that did not work. What is also interesting is that the feature works as expected in a different browser (Firefox) and even works in Chrome on another machine, so its specific to an instance of Chrome.

Any thoughts on what might be causing the issue?

I am on a MacOS Monterrey Version 12.4 with an M1 Max chip.

A (blurry) screenshot of my situation after attempting to drag a file from the left hand browser.

[image]

Comment: We also see this phenomenon in our application with Chrome 106.0.5249.91 (Windows and Linux). Starting a drag and drop operation immediately clears the screen until the page is reloaded. In one situation, we were able to fix the issue in the application: The drag-start handler threw an exception which triggered this behavior. But we still have another situation where a drag-and-drop operation doesn't throw exceptions, but Chrome still clears the screen and doesn't redraw it.